# Excel generated report with more than 75 000 rows?

Tags: excel, oracle, report

I'm using rwservlet to generate an oracle reports rdf in a excel compatible format. The desformat used is ENHANCED SPREADSHEET. 
The problem is the report returns a lot of rows and enhanced spreadsheet only allows up to 75 000 rows. The result is that not all my data is displayed.

From my research it seems that i'd need to switch to delimited format in order to have all data displayed, however the client wants the reports generated in excel to make use of its formulas.
Is there any way to get oracle reports to generate all the data into an excel compatible format? Or can i use a procedure to do this instead of oracle reports?

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: the client wants to use the formulas available in excel.

Comment: how do you come to 75.000 allowed rows? old excel has 65536 rows allowed and new limit is 1,048,576 ?

Comment: what excel version does your customer use?

Comment: the doc says:"Oracle Reports 11g Release 1 introduces a new spreadsheet output format, ENHANCEDSPREADSHEET, which enables you to burst and distribute reports to the spreadsheet format,as well as generate large data sets (up to 75,000 rows) to spreadsheets"
I'm building a link that looks like: http://rep_server/rwservlet?report=rep_name&desformat=ENHANCEDSPREADSHEET&destype=CACHE. This prompts a download of a file named rwservlet.xls which is the actual report opened in excel.I can't figure out if i can modify the extension to xlsx.Oracle's doc on rwservlet's params doesn't give me much hope

Comment: The client uses office 2010. But the report is generated with extension .xls. I tried saving it and changing the extension to .xlsx to see if at least it opens and it gave me an error saying it can't open that file.

Comment: You might think about saving in a csv format to a file. Excel will correctly open and parse the file into columns.